# CloudFront usage through PHP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to monitor how much bandwidth is being used for a time period for each distribution programmatically - Is there any way I can make an API call through PHP to CF and/or CloudWatch to get this value ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-metrics-dimensions.html)?

Comment: I read through it but can't find anything that will allow me to. Can you please point me in the direction ?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront [exposes several metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-metrics-dimensions.html) through CloudWatch.

Specifically, the metrics are `Requests` (the count of requests), `BytesDownloaded`, `BytesUploaded`, `TotalErrorRate` (percentage of requests with 4xx/5xx HTTP responses combined together), and `4xxErrorRate`/`5xxErrorRate` for the 4xx/5xx HTTP error classes tallied separately.

[GetMetricStatistics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-monitoring-2010-08-01.html#getmetricstatistics) in the PHP SDK V3 for AWS allows you to fetch the collected data from CloudWatch via the API.  You can, according to the docs, fetch up to 1,440 data points.

If you are using the older V2 SDK for PHP it offers [getMetricStatistics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.CloudWatch.CloudWatchClient.html#_getMetricStatistics) to interact with CloudWatch, as well.